# Symfony2 Twig custom filter in asset

Tags: symfony, twig, absolute-path, assetic

I'm nearly new in Symfony2 and I have a little question:

I'm developing an email template, which has txt and html parts (no problem with it)

The only 'problem' I have is with the absolute paths of assets in TWIG.

Inside my email.html.twig file I have something like this:

`<img src="{{ asset('images/my-image.png') }}" alt="My image" />` but it writes the route with relative path.

I discovered a little solution to add absolute paths, something like this:

```
{% set abs = app.request.scheme ~  '://' ~ app.request.host %}
<img src="{{ abs ~ asset('images/my-image.png') }}" alt="My image" />
```

It works! But I want to improve this solution and also learn to create custom filters (I read the documentation, but I got a bit lost)

I want to create something like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/my-image.png' | absolute) }}" alt="My image" />
```

But I don't know how to properly override the assetics extension. Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a little hard to copy paste the solution but I can make a short cookbook so you can go step by step and do it yourself:

1) You will have to implement Assetic/Filter/FilterInterface

2) If you look at the FilterInterface class, you will see that you have to to implement two methods: filterLoad and filterDump.

So, you will do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace You\YourBundle\Assetic\Filter;

use Assetic\Asset\AssetInterface;
use Assetic\Filter\FilterInterface;

class YourAsseticFilter implements FilterInterface
{ 
    public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
    {

          // do something

    }


    public function filterDump(AssetInterface $asset)
    {
        $content = $asset->getContent();

        // do something

        $asset->setContent($content);
    }


}
```

And after you to this, you have to something very similar to registering twig extensions in services.yml in YourBundle. Sure, it depens if you use YML, XML... configuration. I use yml so I will type it in yml :)

```
parameters:
    your_bundle.class: You\YourBundle\Assetic\Filter\YourAsseticFilter

services:
    your_bundle.assetic.your_assetic_filter:
        class: %your_bundle.class%
        tags:
            - { name: assetic.filter }
            - { alias: yourChosenNameForYourNewAsseticFilter }
```

And then you call it like | yourChosenNameForYourNewAsseticFilter, of course.

Comment: Hi mate! I know how to create a TWIG filter (but thank you anyway). The problem is that I don't know how to code my necessity: How to overrride the assets extension to add the protocol and sites host.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how to override some existing assetic extension but if you can simply a new extension, you can get the data about the protocol and site host in the YourAsseticFilter class. But I don't know if it helps...

Comment: We'll when I could try your solution I come back to this post for feedback. Thanks for your time, we'll see if it could work.

Comment: You will probably have to inject some services into YourAsseticFilter throught services.yml and then take the apropriate object with constructor of YourAsseticFilter since you need to take protocol and site host... I do not know without checking which part of Symfony holds those data but I guess the logic is similar to the situation when you need doctrine in some service. I presume you already know how to inject for example doctrine in service. If you don't find a solution, we can google it and we will find a solution for sure. Good luck :)

Comment: I had to use one tag, set to "{ name: assetic.filter, alias: myAlias }". Otherwise I got an error about a missing "name".